# Vue v-for data does not get updated on properties change

Tags: vue.js

So I render a list of items like

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="item.id">
  <item :item="item"></item>
</div>
```

Items looks like this:

```
items: Array[20]
  0: Object
    sold: false
  1: Object
    sold: true
```

Now I display these items using an overlay. Once an item is marked as "sold" for example, I use VueX to change "items" by watching the VueX data. So I say

```
items[0].sold = true
```

Now items was changed sucessfully, however, my list does not re-render and thus no change is shown. Any idea why and how to overcome this? One solution would be to watch in every "item" component for a change, but that would mean that I could have hundreds of Vue compontents watching for a change and I guess that would be not a nice solution performance wise.

Thank you!

Comment: Well, the `<item>` component only receives the item id as a prop, not the whole (updated) item. So how do you get the item data within that component? There's your problem, presumably. I would simply pass the whole item down instead of the id.

Comment: If it doesn't listen to property updates you can always force vue to update by using `$forceUpdate();`

Comment: $forceUpdate() does not work

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to change your current code to:

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="item.id">
  <item :item="item"></item>
</div>
```

and then in your Item Component you can render whatever information about your item you want. This way you also get the reactivity about the *sold* property of each item, as you wanted.

Comment: sorry that was my mistake. I am already doing what you suggested